# my asp site loading slow on iis7

Tags: asp.net, performance, iis-7

i host a simple file download site which runs on asp.net on iis7 webserver. the site was ok until it was published, now the problem is that server responds very late. when i access the site from a browser on my server, it is fast. but when i access from other computers, site keeps loading n loading until it gets response from server and it quickly loads the page. i don't know how to fix this thing. 
additionally, when i reboot the server, site loads faster from other computers for some minutes, then again it becomes too slow.. 
maybe it is due to people visiting the site, and some configuration needed prevent this slow response issue. curently it takes about 30 seconds before it starts getting response from server. I m using windows server 2008 r2 with 2.5 GHz dual core xeon processor & 2gb ram.
If somebody knows the solution to this problem, kindly give me step by step instructions as i got this server configured by an external expert, and i have little knowledge of server configurations.
WAiting for your Assistance :)

Comment: Taking about 30 seconds sounds like it's waiting for something and then timing out. Are you accessing any externally hosted resources like JavaScript, CSS or images?

Comment: i use ads on the page, but still there should be some response.and as i said , when i reboot server or even reconnect internet access of webserver, my site loads like a flash in 2 or 3 seconds. but after some minutes it become too slow waiting for response.

Comment: i have restarted now, check it here http://95.211.172.73 , it is working like a charm, but after some time, it will faint.

Comment: Is the advert content fetched and rendered from server in html or from client-side such as google ads using javascripts ?

Comment: I've taken a look, it appears to be the wait time for the HTML page and the CSS. The fact that it's the CSS to makes me think that it's not obviously a code issue with the .ASPX page. What's the load on the server like (CPU, network)

Answer (score 0):

I know improving and fixing sever issues are harder to check and fix. What I believe is profiling your web application will indeed help you in your case.

And I think you should profile the site for any memory issues and if you have database also then database connection issues and performance (of course).

You need to run profiler for memory and performance checks on your site in local IIS7 using any of the these tools or if you can find any other at your convenience to use.

- **In-built visual studio 2010 ultimate profiling tools**

  - [Find Application Bottlenecks with Visual Studio Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc337887.aspx)
- **Red-Gate profiler tools**

  - [ANTS Performance Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/)
  - [ANTS Memory Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/)

I have used Red-Gate profiler tools and it really helped me. You need to check the usage videos to get familiar with any of the profiler tool before use.

Check [Visual Studio Toolbox: Performance Profiling](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Visual-Studio-Toolbox/Visual-Studio-Toolbox-Performance-Profiling) for Visual studio profiler tutorial and check [Walkthrough: profiling an ASP.NET application](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/walkthrough) and [Demonstration videos](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/video/) for Red-gate profiler.

I hope my answer was meaningful.